# How to decrypt a RSA encrypted .txt using a public key .pub file?

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I was given an RSA encrypted .txt file to be decrypted  and another .pub file to be used as a key to decrypt the same. I'm new to OpenSSL.

the FILES: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j8581rdazdy0fxs/AABqsREMVMtDK53gtHQNYfkKa?dl=0

```
OpenSSL> rsa -noout -text -inform PEM -in key_5.pub -pubin
```

I executed the following command and got a hexdump of the key_5.pub file. (As attached)

The Modulus value is in hexadecimal form. How do I recover it in decimal form?

Or is there any other way to decrypt the orignal file?

Comment: Why do you want to convert the modulus to decimal? I don't think OpenSSL commandline utility directly supports "decrypting" the ciphertext with the public key. Usually, encryption with the private key (as it seems to be in your case) means digital signature: hash the data to be signed and encrypt the hash with the private key. Either way, this question is not about programming and is therefore better suited for [su].

Comment: The public key decrypt operation correspond to `verify`. Therefore the decryption may be performed as `openssl rsautl -verify -pubin -raw -inkey .\key_5.pub -in .\crypto_5.txt`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).